# Hibernate обновление данных со связью many to many

Tags: java, html, hibernate, spring-boot

Есть 3 таблицы в БД.
1 - Item

```
(
    id          serial primary key,
    name        varchar   not null,
    description text      not null,
    created     timestamp not null,
    done        boolean default false
);
```

2 - Category

```
create table categories
(
    id   serial primary key,
    nameCategory varchar not null unique
);

INSERT INTO categories (nameCategory) VALUES ('Work');
INSERT INTO categories (nameCategory) VALUES ('Relaxation');
```

3 - participates

```
create table participates
(
    id      serial primary key,
    item_id int not null references item (id),
    category_id int not null references categories (id)
);
```

Связь между Item и Category many to many.

У меня не получается обновить Category в объекте Item в БД. При изменение категории Item заходит в repositrory обновленным но в базе категории остаются старые, я думаю у меня не правильно написанные запрос на update.

Модель Item

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_item")
    private User user;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime created;
    private boolean done;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "participates",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "item_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")}
    )
    private Set<Categories> category = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Модель Category

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Categories {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Integer id;

    private String nameCategory;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nameCategory;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
  @GetMapping("/formUpdateItem/{itemId}")
    public String formUpdateItem(Model model, @PathVariable("itemId") int id, HttpSession session) {
        model.addAttribute(ITEMS, this.service.findById(id));
        model.addAttribute("category", this.categoryService.findAll());
        sessions(model, session);
        return "updateItem";
    }

    @PostMapping("/updateItem")
    public String updateItem(@ModelAttribute Item item,
                             @RequestParam(value = "category.id", required = false) List<Integer> categoriesId) {
        Set<Categories> categories = new HashSet<>();
        if (categoriesId != null) {
            categoriesId.forEach(value -> categories.add(this.categoryService.findById(value)));
            item.setCategory(categories);
        }
        this.service.update(item);
        return String.format("redirect:/formItemId/%s", item.getId());
    }
```

Form

```
            <form th:action="@{/updateItem}" method="POST" th:object="${items}" style="background: #bdb9b9">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" th:field="*{id}"/>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" th:field="*{name}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description"
                           th:field="*{description}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="category.id">Category</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="category.id" name="category.id" multiple="multiple" size="4" required>
                        <option th:each="category : ${category}" th:value="${category.id}"
                                th:text="${category.nameCategory}"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div style="text-align: center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Repository

```
    private static final String UPDATE_QUERY = "update Item i " +
            "set i.name = :Name, i.description = :Description where i.id = :Id";

    public void update(Item item) {
        System.out.println(item);
        this.factory(session -> session.createQuery(
                        UPDATE_QUERY).
                setParameter("Id", item.getId())
                .setParameter("Name", item.getName())
                .setParameter("Description", item.getDescription())
                .executeUpdate());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил метод

```
   private static final String UPDATE_QUERY = "update Item i " +
            "set i.name = :Name, i.description = :Description where i.id = :Id";

    public void update(Item item) {
        System.out.println(item);
        this.factory(session -> session.createQuery(
                        UPDATE_QUERY).
                setParameter("Id", item.getId())
                .setParameter("Name", item.getName())
                .setParameter("Description", item.getDescription())
                .executeUpdate());
    }
```

На полную замену объекта

```
    public void update(Item item) {
        var findItem = findById(item.getId());
        this.factory(session -> {
            item.setUser(findItem.getUser());
            item.setCreated(findItem.getCreated());
            session.saveOrUpdate(item);
            return null;
        });
    }
```

Всё заработало.